# Problems with Nsight and libraries

Tags: iostream, nsight

Warning: newbie question!
I create a new empty project in the Nsight IDE, then I create a file "hello.cpp":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Debugger output:

```
In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [new] Error 1
```

It doesn't find cout, even though I see that  is there (in fact I see
that it has been included on the top right of the Nsight window).
Apart from this simple I'm having problems with lots of libraries in Nsight, this same code in Code::Blocks doesn't have any problem!
Does Nsight work differently? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found out that Nsight Eclipse is very particular with the extensions of the files.

In my installation I have to explicitly write down the '.h' to the header files, like this `#include <iostream.h>` otherwise they are not recognized.

Another issue I found is with the extensions of the source files themselves. Nsight does not like when you have a .c extension, in the sense that some instances included in some headers are not found. Whenever I change the extension to .cu, .cpp, or .cc the instances are linked with the appropriate header.

I would recommend you to put the header extension '.h'. Let us know if it works that way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply mrei. Actually if I switch to <iostream.h> I don't see any improvement but the marker Unresolved inclusion: <iostream.h>.

Comment: You are right! I just tried and `iostream` does not like with '.h'. I am going to ask some experts, wait a minute.